# Discord.js Packet Loss

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, packet-loss

After running my bot for a while using discord.js/voice the packet loss is horrible, it loses 1 packet every second. Is this a memory leak? I switched providers and it still happens. Note: When I start the bot there is no packet loss but after a couple of hours there's a lot of it.

Can someone please help? (I use `process.on('unhandledRejection')` and `process.on('uncaughtException')` if that is a problem since I've seen issues with it.)

Packet Loss Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by [installing Sodium and @discord/opus with npm.](https://discordjs.guide/voice/#barebones)

Comment: Welcome! Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.